# Print documents go to the print spool with status printing, but its not printing document using rawprint nuget packages C#

Tags: c#, printing, nuget-package

I am implementing print document without print dialog using rawprint nuget packages C#

When i print word document with print dialog then it adds to print queue with status "Printing" and successfully
print the document.

When i print PDF document with "PrinterName" and FilePath using rawprint nuget packages C#, then it's add to print queue with status "Printing" But no print out from printer.

My code sample given bellow

```
public void printPDF(string printerName)
        {
            // Absolute path to your PDF to print (with filename)
            string combinedPdf = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Content("~/temp/") + "conbined_5248422286163515789.pdf";
            // The name of the PDF that will be printed (just to be shown in the print queue)
            string Filepath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(combinedPdf);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Filepath))
            {
                string Filename = "conbined_5248422286163515789.pdf";
                // The name of the printer that you want to use
                // Note: Check step 1 from the B alternative to see how to list
                // the names of all the available printers with C#
                string PrinterName = printerName;

                // Create an instance of the Printer
                IPrinter printer = new Printer();

                // Print the file
                printer.PrintRawFile(PrinterName, Filepath, Filename);
            }
        }
```

Please help and suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
string Filepath = @"\\YOURSERVER\PATH\Path\" + Label1.Text + "-" + label2.Text + ".pdf";
string Filename = label1.Text + "-" + Label2.Text + ".pdf";
string PrinterName = @"\\server01\Print-11"; //Adress of the Printer with name!

// Create an instance of the Printer

IPrinter printer = new Printer();

// Print the file:
printer.PrintRawFile(PrinterName, Filepath, Filename);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although this might work, you should add some explanation what you do differently.

Comment: I have tested the same code but same thing happen. that means it's add to print queue with status "Printing" But no print out from printer.